# ¿Como puedo hacer que al seleccionar un editext en el teclado salga una lupa? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: Como puedo lograr que apaezca la lupa en un edit text]

Estoy realizando una aplicacion movil, la cual busco realizar un buscador, pero quisiera que al teclear en el edittext del buscado me salga el icono de la lupa en el teclado, ¿Como es posible?

Answer (score 5):

En lugar de un EditText puedes utilizar el widget SearchView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias! nuevo en la comunidad y super contento de pertenercer y ver lo rapido y acertado que comparten conocimiento.

Comment: @AndersonAcuña toda la razon

Answer (score 3):

#### `EditText` con lupa.

Una opción usando el `EditText` es definiendo el icono mediante la propiedad `android:drawableLeft`, y usando la propiedad `android:hint` para el texto:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtSearchProduct"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Busca en Twitter"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_magnifglass" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo recomendable es usar el widget [**SearchView**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView) que tiene implementada la animación y el borrado del texto dentro del widget:

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchSomething"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[image]

Para el texto de sugerencia usa la propiedad  [**android:queryHint**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#attr_android:queryHint), ejemplo:

```
android:queryHint="Busca en Twitter"
```